# how can i resign the UILongPressGesture in one view and pass it to another?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement a drag movement of an inner uiview from one uiview container into another.

i'm having trouble dismissing the UILongPressGesture on the first view and pass the gesture on to the second view. i have the UILongPressGestureRecognizer on all 3 views (first container, inner and second container).

I'm dragging the inner view inside the first container and once i recognize i have reached the second container i want to resign the gesture on the first container and so trigger its UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded and on the second container trigger UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.

is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end what i did is as follows:

to resign the UILongPressGestureRecognizer on the first container i used

```
    theLongPressGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    theLongPressGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
```

which triggered the UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled state on the first container.
then on the second container i just activated A pan gesture to move the inner view around.